# Android infinite animation

Tags: android

```html
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    >

</rotate>
```

```
    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context , R.anim.rotation);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

   imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(!animation.isInitialized()){
               imageButton.startAnimation(animation);
            }else{
               imageButton.clearAnimation();
                animation.reset();
                animation.cancel();
            }

        }
    });
```

Hi, I have this code with an onclick set up that would start rotating the button on click and stop if the button is clicked again.. however, only first click that starts the animation is working here. Animation just resets on clicking the button when animation is running.
Tried it in combination with animation.reset().

Comment: post your xml for anim.

Comment: <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    >

</rotate>

Comment: try adding `android:repeatCount="infinite"`

Comment: it's set on OnclickListener:       animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

Answer (score 0):

You create a new Animation object every time you click on the button. Try initializing it outside of the `onClick` function and just handle the checking if it is currently running inside the `onClick`.

Comment: Argh... i moved the animation out of onclick block... but still the animation does not stops

Comment: I think it's because `!animation.hasEnded()` always returns true so you keep starting the animation all over again.

Comment: Did this change :: Now, I can stop the animation however, when loaded first time, upon first click the animation works. When stopped and try to sart again, first click doesnot work.. when I click second time on the button it works. It doesn't work with hasEnded() or hasStarted() at all.                             
    if(!animation.isInitialized()){
                    imageButton.startAnimation(animation);
                }else{
                    animation.reset();
                    animation.cancel();
                }

Comment: Try calling `animation.cancel()` first `before animation.reset()`